# How to make a circle on the LaunchScreen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uilabel, launch-screen

I made a Cocoa Touch Class called `BlackCircle`, a `UILabel` subview which called the `drawRect()` method to make a black circular label. I dragged a `UILabel` onto the `LaunchScreen.xib` file, and when I assigned the Cocoa Touch Class File as the class of the `UILabel`, I got an error-

> "Launch Screen may not use instances of `BlackCircle`".

It works fine on the main.storyboard file, but it doesn't work on the `LaunchScreen.xib` file. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You can't http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/12/24/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html

Answer (score 5):

LaunchScreen will not load your custom instances. Remember the app hasn't launched yet. Thus you cannot have custom instances.

You are only allowed to use basic UIKit classes like UIView, UIImageView, UILabel, etc.

Your best bet would be to make an image resource for the black circular label and import it to the LaunchScreen.xib

Comment: Then does this mean that I cannot have an animated LaunchScreen also? @Vig

Comment: @KrishWadhwana yeah you cannot have any animation on LaunchScreen

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way!

You can add an image view and use SF image like "circle.fill" (just enter the name in the topmost text field) and use tint color to style it in your way.